# Gnumeric Python plugin and console - Missing functions in newer Debian installation

Tags: python, console, debian, missing-features, gnumeric

I am missing some of the most important functions of the Python plugin of Gnumeric on a newer Debian system. After starting the Python console (Gnumeric menu option Tools --> Python console) I get:

```
>>> import Gnumeric
 >>> dir()
 ['Gnumeric', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
>>> dir(Gnumeric)
['FALSE', 'GnumericError', 'GnumericErrorDIV0',
'GnumericErrorNA', 'GnumericErrorNAME', 'GnumericErrorNULL',
'GnumericErrorNUM', 'GnumericErrorREF', 'GnumericErrorVALUE',
'TRUE', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'functions']
```

According to the Gnumeric documentation, the output of dir(Gnumeric) should be something like:

```
>>> dir(Gnumeric)
['Boolean', 'CellPos', 'FALSE', 'GnumericError', 'GnumericErrorDIV0',
'GnumericErrorNA', 'GnumericErrorNAME', 'GnumericErrorNULL',
'GnumericErrorNUM', 'GnumericErrorRECALC', 'GnumericErrorREF',
'GnumericErrorVALUE', 'MStyle', 'Range', 'TRUE', '__doc__',
'__name__', 'functions', 'plugin_info', 'workbook_new', 'workbooks']
```

I miss relevant functions as 'CellPos', 'MStyle', 'Range', 'plugin_info', 'workbook_new', 'workbooks'. Other functions also changed obviously.

The files plugin.xml and ui-console-menu.xml delivered with the distribution contain no commented out statements.

Am I eventually overlooking something? Or might this be a bug? Unfortunately I haven't found any reference to this possible issue in the forums.

My Debian and gnumeric system

Linux  6.1.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.4-1 (2023-01-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Bookworm/sid

Gnumeric version 1.12.53 installed with the help of Synaptic (or apt-get). Packages:

girl1.2-gnumeric 1.12.53-1.1+b1
gnumeric 1.12.53-1.1+b1
gnumeric-common 1.12.53-1.1
gnumeric-doc 1.12.53
gnumeric-plugins-extra 1.12.53-1.1+b1

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

After some very frustrating days I finally found an answer to my question of some days ago.

The module Gnumeric is obsolete, it was replaced by the module gi. See the following links for details.

```
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnumeric/-/issues/687
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnumeric/-/blob/master/introspection/README
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnumeric/-/blob/master/test/t3001-introspection-simple.pynter
```

The official documentation of Gnumeric is unfortunately not up-to-date.

Thanks in any case for your interest.